# Number of ways to make a bracelet with n beads and m colors

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving a problem on the Art of Problem Solving website that was posed like this:

How many ways can the $7$ spokes of a wheel be painted such that each spoke can be either red, green, or blue?

Another user and I were solving the problem together, and it turns out the answer is $315$. If we list the $7$ spokes in some order, there are $3^7 $ ways of coloring each spoke. Subtracting the three combinations where all the spokes are the same color, we get $3^7-3$. To remove the duplicates (combinations that are indistinguishable under the rotation of the wheel), divide by $7$ because each of the remaining combinations are a duplicate of $6$ others. Finally add the three combinations where all the spokes are the same color to get $\frac{3^7-3}{7}+3 = 315$.

My question is, is it possible to generalize this problem for $n$ spokes and $m$ colors? I realize that if $n$ is prime, then the formula is $\frac{m^n-m}{n}+m$.

Please excuse the terrible wording and explanation. Those are not my strong points. If you need more clarification, feel free to ask in the comments.

Thanks,

The Turtle

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will keep that in mind next time. I must have forgot... I haven't posted a question in such a long time.

Comment: Your technique generalizes immediately to **prime** numbers of spokes, and as a corollary yields the important *Fermat's (little) Theorem*. The situation for composite $n$ is more complicated.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I just made an edit about that. Thanks!

Comment: By "duplicates" do you mean colorings that are indistinguishable under the rotation of the wheel/spokes?

Comment: @M47145 Yes. However, reflections are considered different combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is: Yes! It is possible to generalize this to $n$ spokes and $m$ colors.

This type of coloring problem, where colorings are considered the same if they are symmetric to one another (via rotation, reflection, etc), can be solved generally using **Polya's Enumeration Theorem**. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) is a link to the Wikipedia article if you are interested.

Basically what it does is provides a method for finding the number of equivalent $m$-colorings of $n$ objects under any desired group of symmetries $G$ acting on the $n$ objects. In the spokes/necklace/bracelet problem you mentioned the relevant group would be the cyclic group $C_n$ acting on $n$ spokes. Without going into all the details, Polya's Enumeration Theorem gives the following general formula for the number of $m$-colorings of $n$ spokes:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \phi(d)m^{n/d} $$

where $\phi$ denotes the Euler totient function and the sum is over positive integer divisors $d$ of $n$.

So to work your example using this formula, we have $m=3$ and $n=7$. The formula gives: 
$$\frac{1}{7} \sum_{d|7} \phi(d)3^{7/d} = \frac{1}{7}(3^7+6\cdot 3^1)=\frac{2205}{7}=315$$